# Azure Function functionTimeout per environment

Tags: azure-functions

My Function App has host.json with `functionTimeout` for development environment.

I would like to configure `functionTimeout` also for production environment with a different value.

Can this value be configured in Azure portal? I could not find it in settings.

Can there be a separate host.json for production environment in the Visual Studio project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your function app and click "App files", then you can configure `functionTimeout`.
[image]

You also need to check this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout) about the default timeout and maximum timeout for each plan type.
[image]

And as far as I know, only one host.json can exist in one project in local Visual Studio project. So I think we can just configure different `functionTimeout` on portal when you deploy the function project from local to azure.

Comment: Just adding to Hury's answer. If you want to be lazier and dont want to modify host.json file every time during or after deployment, you can use an app settings to override host.json value. In this case, add "AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout" to your function app in portal and set the intended value for production env. Check out the official doc for more details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values

Comment: note that the "AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout" method only works on Azure Functions V2+